# Running Minikube Cluster as Jenkins Agent

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, minikube

I have a container instance: jenkins, and kubernetes cluster: minikube both running on my local machine. I can't figure out a way to integrate minikube in jenkins. Below is how i set things up.

```
Setup Minikube
    - minikube start
    - replace cert and key values in .kube/config with hardcoded data

Setup Jenkins 
    - docker run --name jenkins -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --network minikube jenkins/jenkins:lts

Integrate Kubernetes in Jenkins 
    - install kubernetes plugin 
    - configure cloud -> add a new cloud -> kubernetes -> kubernetes cloud details  
        - create credential: secret file, use the file with .kube/config
        - click test connection -> Error testing connection : java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:{port}
```

I've been stuck with this problem for a few good days and it's driving me insane. My jenkins instance is already running in the same network with the minikube.

[problem-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mxh3.png)

Comment: Can't you run Jenkins using helm chart instead of doing this ? I am not understanding the use case why these should be connected

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar thanks man, your suggestion just works! :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP was able to use Helmchart to install Jenkins. Using helm chart makes it easier to install as well as manage application deployed on kubernetes.